# Calculate possible combinations from dynamically generated arrays

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have few dynamically generated s. s can be 2,3,4,5 or more. Is it possible to calculate the combinations of values of the arrays, where the first array values are always the first value of the combinations.

```
[attributes_id_1] = 
(
    [0] =  5

)
    [attributes_id_2] = 
(
    [0] = 8
    [1] = 9
    [2] = 10
)
    [attributes_id_3] = 
(
    [0] = 12
    [1] = 15
)
```

Resulting:
5,8,12
5,9,12
5,10,12
5,8,15
5,9,15
5,10,15

```
[attributes_id_1] => 
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
    )

[attributes_id_2] => 
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 9
    )

[attributes_id_3] => 
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 13
    )

[attributes_id_4] => 
    (
        [0] => 14
        [1] => 15
    )
```

Resulting:
5,8,12,14
5,8,12,15
5,8,13,14
5,8,13,15
5,9,12,14
.....
6,8,12,14
6,8,12,15
6,8,13,14
6,8,13,15
6,9,12,14
.....

```
[attributes_id_1] => 
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
    )

[attributes_id_2] => 
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 10
    )
```

Resulting:
5,8
5,9
5,10
6,8
6,9
6,10

Comment: just use a combination on all Arrays but the first ad then just foreach and add the first didget

Comment: I managed to do it with Cartesian product (  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product  )